# verbatim vs verbatum

Tags: etymology, latin

I know that *verbatim* has a Latin origin, but why is it not spelled *verbatum*?

English does not seem to have many Latin words that end in *‑im*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that it’s spelled *verbatim* is because the word was copied from Latin verbatim. It was not respelled. It would be a travesty to use some other spelling for that word, for such a respelling would put the lie to the very word itself.

Other words of that form attested by the OED include *alternatim, gradatim, guttatim, literatim, nominatim, punctatim, punctuatim, seriatim, stillatim,* and *syllabatim*.

The *‑atim* suffix in Latin is an adverbial suffix meaning *‑by‑* that noun. Each of those means by that noun, or noun by noun, making *verbatim* word by (or *for*) word, *literatim* letter by letter, et cetera.

Comment: Exactly. *verbatim,* word by word; *gradatim,* step  by step; *seriatim,* one by one.

Comment: The suffix *-im* indicates adverbality. Cf. *interim*. The origin of the suffix is an archaïc accusative ending.